# InfoPath Form Load Rule not working

Tags: workflow, infopath

I've got two form views on an InfoPath form, when the user submits the form I have a Work Flow action to update a field called 'IQ Field View' to 1.The 'IQ' field is initially set to 0.

In InfoPath I have Form Rule with the condition that if the IQ Field View = 1 the switch views to the second form view. When the form s submitted the 'IQ' field updates to '1' however the view doesn't switch.

I'm using SP 2010.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the view not switched when you open the form again **after** the IQ=1?

Comment: No, the field update but the view remains the same.

Comment: could you please share your rule?